# Как настроить обработку адресов?

Tags: битрикс

Доброго времени суток 
На сайте необходимо для каждой страницы в зависимости от города добавлять поддиректорию ( пример [евросеть](http://euroset.ru/)) 
Добавление в адресную строку нужной поддиректории я сделал, но теперь необходимо настроить обработку адресов, что бы к примеру если я обращаюсь к странице `site.ru/moskva/catalog/razdel/element` отображалась страница `site.ru/catalog/razdel/element` (без города) и так для всех страниц сайта

 В urlrewrite добавил правило (для начала решил сделать каталог)

```
$arUrlRewrite = array(
array(
    "CONDITION" => "#^([a-zA-Z0-9%\\;\\\$\\&\\*\\.\\/\\^\\:\\?\\_\\=\\-]+)\\/irk\\/products\\/([0-9]+)\\/([0-9]+)#",
    "RULE" => "/products/\$2/\$3",
    "ID" => "",
    "PATH" => "",
),);
```

у каталога ЧПУ настроен как /#SECTION_ID#/#ELEMENT_ID#/, соответствует условию, но почему то не срабатывает

Comment: вроде правильный регексп http://regexr.com/3e4lj отрабатывает

Comment: да, я проверял его работоспособность и вообще писал его через https://regex101.com/, вопрос в том почему он не срабатывает в urlrewrite?

Comment: а какой урл не срабатывает? вообще никакие переменные не приходят?

Comment: я вот смотрю в свой урлреврайт. Попробуй не эскейпить "/" в адресе. /irk/products/(\d+)/(\d+)

Comment: попробовал, не помогло, не срабатывает вообще ни один адрес каталога

Comment: Сразу не заметил. Руле вообще то должно выглядеть так "RULE" => "/products/detail.php?SECTION_ID=$2&ELEMENT_ID=$3". Может поэтому и не приходит

Comment: т.е "RULE" => "SECTION_ID=$2&ELEMENT_ID=$3", а "PATH" => "/products/detail.php"